# Distinguishing GZIP and non-GZIP format doesn't work

Tags: java, io, gzip

I'm working on an [NBT](http://wiki.vg/NBT) scanner software. It is supposed to read NBT data from files both with or without [GZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) compression. I use the following code to determine if the file is compressed in GZIP format. Assuming it is valid. (I'm using a FileInputStream extension that supports mark/reset)

```
public static InputStream GZIPCheck(InputStream in) throws IOException{
    in.mark(1);
    int header = in.read();
    in.reset();
    if(header > Byte.MAX_VALUE){
        return new GZIPInputStream(in);
    }
    return in;
}
```

The `NBT` format's prefix is a signed short (any value) that cannot be negative and the `GZIP` format starts with a negative short:

```
public final static int GZIP_MAGIC = 0x8b1f;
```

That makes it easy to distinguish between the two. I read the first byte, if it is negative, (unsigned version is bigger than Byte.MAX_VALUE) then it can't be `NBT`, so I try the GZIPInputStream. (If it fails, then the file is not valid.) If the first byte is positive, (or zero) then it can't be `GZIP` since it is inconsistent with `GZIP_MAGIC`, so I don't use it.

Here's the thing: My method always returns the `in` parameter no matter what valid [file](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/NBT_format) I read. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the API doc for InputStream.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) it does the following

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255.

[According to RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#page-5) a GZIP file starts with ID1 and ID2 and

> have the fixed values ID1 = 31 (0x1f, \037), ID2 = 139 (0x8b, \213), to identify the file as being in gzip format.

Calling `InputStream.read()` on a valid GZIP file will return 31 or 0x1f, a single byte and not the whole magic number that consists of two bytes. And as 31 is lower than `Byte.MAX_VALUE` (which is 127) the condition never resembles true in case of a valid GZIP file.

You should consider checking both ID1 and ID2 for being exactly the expected values for GZIP files.

Comment: "...not the whole magic number that consists of two bytes." I knew that. It is in two bytes. Which means the first byte should be 0x8b or -117 or unsigned 139. (The latter of which is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) Right?

Comment: No, the first number is ID1 and that is 0x1f or 31. If you call in.read() again you will get ID2 and that is 0x8b or 139.

Comment: This means that GZIPInputStream reads the bytes of a short in the opposite order as DataInputStream. Well that's kind of...

Comment: Bytes are always read in the same order. However interpreting two bytes as a 16-bit integer can be done in two ways, referred to as little-endian (least significant byte first) or big-endian (most significant byte first). Which will be done will normally depend on the endianess of the machine. Intel is little endian.

Comment: You can also check that the third byte is an 8.